# Grails 1.3.7 / Java 7 Compatibility

Tags: grails, java

Has anyone had luck running a Grails 1.3.7 app with Java 7?  I created a brand new Grails 1.3.7 app and tried running it under Java 7.  I get the below error but the app appears to run ok.  We have a few 1.3.7 apps that we're reluctant to upgrade to Grails 2.x, so any ideas would be much appreciated.

```
Unable to use direct char[] access of java.lang.String
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: count
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1899)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.StringCharArrayAccessor.<clinit>(StringCharArrayAccessor.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.StreamCharBuffer.readAsString(StreamCharBuffer.java:531)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.StreamCharBuffer.toString(StreamCharBuffer.java:552)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.FastStringWriter.getValue(FastStringWriter.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.FastStringWriter.toString(FastStringWriter.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPageParser.startTag(GroovyPageParser.java:1119)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPageParser.page(GroovyPageParser.java:801)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPageParser.generateGsp(GroovyPageParser.java:380)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPageParser.parse(GroovyPageParser.java:326)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesTemplateEngine.buildPageMetaInfo(GroovyPagesTemplateEngine.java:584)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesTemplateEngine.createTemplate(GroovyPagesTemplateEngine.java:493)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesTemplateEngine.createTemplateWithResource(GroovyPagesTemplateEngine.java:473)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesTemplateEngine.createTemplate(GroovyPagesTemplateEngine.java:246)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesTemplateEngine.createTemplateForUri(GroovyPagesTemplateEngine.java:373)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesTemplateEngine.createTemplateForUri(GroovyPagesTemplateEngine.java:345)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesTemplateEngine.createTemplate(GroovyPagesTemplateEngine.java:262)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.GroovyPageView.renderWithTemplateEngine(GroovyPageView.java:146)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.GroovyPageView.renderMergedOutputModel(GroovyPageView.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter.renderViewForUrlMappingInfo(UrlMappingsFilter.java:260)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlMappingsFilter.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.obtainContent(GrailsPageFilter.java:245)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.doFilter(GrailsPageFilter.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.filter.GrailsReloadServletFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsReloadServletFilter.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's annoying but safe to ignore, and fixed in 2.1.1 and 2.2 - see https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/2359 for details.

Comment: A bit related - I am still having issues with Grails 2.2 and JDK 1.7 when using maven to build the project. Please see my question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037082/maven-build-for-grails-2-2-0-app-fails-with-jdk-1-7-could-not-find-artifact-com

Answer (score 16):

Set the `JAVA_OPTS` system property:

Windows: `SET JAVA_OPTS=-Dstringchararrayaccessor.disabled=true`

Unix: `export JAVA_OPTS=-Dstringchararrayaccessor.disabled=true`

Comment: do you mean to set an environment variable?

Comment: Hey, probably late, but I am trying to run a legacy code where the grails still use nthe 1.3.7 and java 7. I tried the system property option but it didn't work. FYI: Using Mac and Intellij.

Answer (score 2):

From what I see [in the source code](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-web/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/util/StringCharArrayAccessor.java), you can set the JVM property *stringchararrayaccessor.disabled* to *true*.

Comment: This works with grails 1.3.6 and java7.  The intent of this class seems to be performance related, so it remains to be seen if there is a noticeable impact.

Comment: How do I set this property?

Comment: Any syntax I tried does not work, for example `-Dstringchararrayaccessor.disabled=true`. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Fix for folks observing same issue when starting Collabnet Subversion Edge Server 4.x.

Guess the right place to add the JAVA_OPTS=-Dstringchararrayaccessor.disabled=true, was not the csvn startup script but rather tanukisoft wrapper conf.

Aka, edit $csvn_home/data/conf/csvn-wrapper.conf and add,

> wrapper.java.additional.x=-Dstringchararrayaccessor.disabled=true

(where x is unused next in sequence)