# Maven build for Grails 2.2.0 app fails with JDK 1.7: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.6

Tags: maven, grails, maven-3

*(Updated question title due to updated question/problem, please see my update notes at the bottom!):*

I have a Grails 2.2.0 project, created the pom.xml for it via '`grails create-pom com.mycompany`'.

pom.xml: http://pastebin.com/AVahZjZF

Without modifications to the pom.xml, I run '`mvn package`' with **JDK 1.7** and getting the error below, while with **JDK 1.6** it would work fine.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_11-b21)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)

$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-03-01 01:31:09+0800)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_11, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.7.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home

$ mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.company:company-projectname:0.1 (/Users/myuser/Projects/com.company.web/pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.grails:grails-maven-plugin:2.2.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.6 at specified path /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bundle/Classes/classes.jar -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Unknown packaging: grails-app @ line 8, column 16
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

**I see that the java version is set to 1.6 in grails-maven-plugin-2.2.0.pom, thus my question now: how to make the maven build for my grails project work with JDK 1.7? It looks as if the correct source and target level is set in maven-compiler-plugin (set to 1.6).**

Folder ~/.m2/repository/grails-maven-plugin:

[image]

My environment:

- Maven 3.0.3
- Grails 2.2.0
- GRAILS_HOME set to my Grails directory
- JAVA_HOME set to my JDK 1.7 folder
- JDK 1.7.0_11

Relevant java tools section in my pom.xml:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>tools</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>java.vendor</name>
                <value>Sun Microsystems Inc.</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                <version>${java.version}</version>
                <scope>system</scope>
                <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a known issue and reportedly still happening in Grails 2.2.0 on Mac OS X.

http://jira.grails.org/browse/MAVEN-186

Comment: I have the same issue too. Grails v2.2 and Maven v3.0.3. What was your work around for this?

Comment: Using JDK 1.6 for the moment.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

As mentioned by @Mathias this was a bug in the Grails Maven plugin. The issue has been fixed and all works fine in Grails 2.2.1.

---

I can definitely use *mvn package* here with Grails 2.2.0 from Homebrew, *GRAILS_HOME* unset.

My configuration is Maven 3.0.3 with Grails 2.2.0, on OSX.

I created a "blank" vanilla application without any trouble and packaged it.

```
grails create-app stf && cd stf
grails create-pom com.rimerosolutions.grails
mvn package
```

In my *pom.xml*, the version of *grails-maven-plugin* is set to ${grails.version}.

I'm running OSX, looks like you're running it too.

- Are you using a private maven repository? If so, try to double-check
  the grails-maven-plugin artifact in there.
- If not, just try to clear your *~/.m2/repository* contents for grails-maven-plugin. *rm -rf* that specific plugin cache.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I have the same environment as you, except I have GRAILS_HOME set. But I just found out, the problem is that I was running JDK 1.7, which doesn't seem to work. I just changed to JDK 1.6, cleared the contents of grails-maven-plugin, and it's working now.

Comment: btw: I tried your 3 lines with *JDK 1.7* above to create a blank vanilla application, getting the same error. Is it not recommended in general to use JDK1.7 with grails? (Sorry, Grails n00b). I looked at http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-amp-Java-7-td4638502.html and http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-amp-Java-7-td4638502.html already, but they say 1.7 should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `grails-maven-plugin` says that it needs something in JDK6:

```
tail -n20 ~/.m2/repository/org/grails/grails-maven-plugin/2.0.3/grails-maven-plugin-2.0.3.pom
    <profile>
        <id>jdk_mac</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>mac</family>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <scope>system</scope>
                <systemPath>${java.home}/bundle/Classes/classes.jar</systemPath>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

The solution is to copy the JDK6 `classes.jar` into your current JDK. Fortunately, JDK7 uses a different directory structure, so there should not be any conflict.

```
sudo mkdir -p /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bundle/Classes
sudo cp /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Classes/classes.jar /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bundle/Classes/
```