# Displaying values from database to gsp (view page) using grails

Tags: database, grails

Am a very beginner to this grails
Here is my domain class

```
class Business {

    Integer id
    String company_name 
    String contact_person   
    Integer phone_no
    String status
    String place


    static constraints = {
            id(blank:false,uinque:true)
            company_name(blank:false)
            contact_person(blank:false)
            phone_no(blank:false,uinque:true)
            status(blank:false)
            place(blank:false)
    }
}
```

This is my view page:

```
<g:each in="${business}" status="i" var="BusinessInstance"  >
<tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even' }">
<td>${feildValue(bean: BusinessInstance,feild:"id") }</td>
<td>${feildValue(bean: BusinessInstance,feild:"company_name") }</td>
<td>${feildValue(bean: BusinessInstance,feild:"contact_person") }</td>
```

I just want to display data in my view page am using MySQL Database but am unable to get through please give me some ideas.

Thanks in advance
Have a good day.

Error
    Unable to use direct char[] access of java.lang.String
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: count
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1899)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.StringCharArrayAccessor.       (StringCharArrayAccessor.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.StreamCharBuffer.readAsString(StreamCharBuffer.java:531)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.StreamCharBuffer.toString(StreamCharBuffer.java:552)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.FastStringWriter.getValue(FastStringWriter.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.FastStringWriter.toString(FastStringWriter.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPageParser.startTag(GroovyPageParser.java:1119)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPageParser.page(GroovyPageParser.java:801)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPageParser.generateGsp(GroovyPageParser.java:380)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPageParser.parse(GroovyPageParser.java:326)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesTemplateEngine.buildPageMetaInfo(GroovyPagesTemplateEngine.java:584)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesTemplateEngine.createTemplate(GroovyPagesTemplateEngine.java:493)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesTemplateEngine.createTemplateWithResource(GroovyPagesTemplateEngine.java:473)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesTemplateEngine.createTemplate(GroovyPagesTemplateEngine.java:246)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesTemplateEngine.createTemplateForUri(GroovyPagesTemplateEngine.java:373)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesTemplateEngine.createTemplateForUri(GroovyPagesTemplateEngine.java:345)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesTemplateEngine.createTemplate(GroovyPagesTemplateEngine.java:262)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.GroovyPageView.renderWithTemplateEngine(GroovyPageView.java:146)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.GroovyPageView.renderMergedOutputModel(GroovyPageView.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter.renderViewForUrlMappingInfo(UrlMappingsFilter.java:260)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlMappingsFilter.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.obtainContent(GrailsPageFilter.java:245)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.doFilter(GrailsPageFilter.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.filter.GrailsReloadServletFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsReloadServletFilter.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Unable to use direct char[] access of java.lang.String java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: count.......... –

Comment: please show your controller action for this gsp

Comment: def list={
  
  params.max=Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max'):10,100)
  def business=Business.list(params)
  render(view:"/list",model:[business] );

  
  }

Comment: Check my related answer here, you can use a system property to prevent that error:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510805/grails-1-3-7-java-7-compatibility/16248152#16248152

Comment: yeah i have solved that thnq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably it's because you're using `feildValue`/`feild` instead of `fieldValue`/`field`. Correct code will be:

```
<g:each in="${business}" status="i" var="businessInstance">
  <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even' }">
    <td>${fieldValue(bean: businessInstance, field: "id") }</td>
    <td>${fieldValue(bean: businessInstance, field: "company_name") }</td>
    <td>${fieldValue(bean: businessInstance, field: "contact_person") }</td>
  </tr>
</g:each>
```

And for controller: you need to pass map as a model, not list. Currently you're using `model: [business]`, but have to: `model: [business: business]`

Comment: Unable to use direct char[] access of java.lang.String
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: count..........

Comment: Please add more details about a new error. And make sure that `business` is a list of `Business` instances

Comment: is the domain class i have mentioned above are exact or something is missing?